# How do I reorder the items in Explorer's New menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

How do I move an item above the separator line in the New submenu of Windows 10's right-click context menu?

Is there anything in the Registry that needs to be set?

[image: Right Click Menu Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `Config` subkey under the `ShellNew` key of your file type. Then inside that subkey, add a string value named `BeforeSeparator`. The change should take effect immediately:

[image]

---

To figure this out, I had to dive into the Explorer code. `shell32.dll` contains a `CNewMenu` class that represents the New menu and has a function named `_BeforeSeparator` that determines whether the given entry should be placed before the separator. Here's the important part of that function's disassembly (courtesy of [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)):

[image]

First it uses [`PathMatchSpecW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathmatchspecw) to see if the key name is one of `.lnk`, `.library-ms`, or `Folder`. If it is (red/left path), the item is guaranteed to appear above the line. If not (green/right path), the function checks whether a certain bit (`10h`) in a certain part (`+8`) of the data structure is set.

I needed to find the code responsible for setting that bit. There's a function called `_GetNewObjectInfoForKey` that seems to be responsible for setting up the relevant data structures. Here's part of its disassembly, almost right at the beginning:

[image]

It tries to open a subkey called `Config` and, if successful (red path), uses the `_GetConfigFlags` function to set the part of the data structure containing the bit we're interested in! `_GetConfigFlags` goes along testing for the existence of various entries and setting various bits if appropriate. Here's the part that sets our target bit (`10h`):

[image]

And there we see the desired entry name: `BeforeSeparator`.

Comment: +1 for the assembly. Context menu registry changes can be applied with Explorer restart (without rebooting).

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs the registry file to add new folder with date here it is

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.NewDirectoryBasedOnDate]
@="NewDirectoryBasedOnDate"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\ShellNew]
"Command"="\"CMD\" /D /E:ON /c for /F \"tokens=1-9 delims=.,\\:/\" %%A IN (\"%%date%%\") DO for /F \"tokens=*\" %%a IN (\"%1\") do md \"%%~dpa\\%%A.%%B.%%C\""
"nullfile"=hex:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate]
"FriendlyTypeName"="New Folder With Date"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\DefaultIcon]
@="shell32.dll,3"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\Shell\open]
"LegacyDisable"=hex:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\Shell\open\command]
@="."

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.NewDirectoryBasedOnDate\ShellNew\Config]
"BeforeSeparator"=""
```

Save it as folderwithdate.reg and run it.

Comment: Not sure if this was meant for this question, but this is a cool regedit, thanks.